# In how many ways the letter of the word "RAINBOW" can be arranged such that A must come before I, and I must come before O?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways the letter of the word "RAINBOW" can be arranged such that
A must come before I, and I must come before O?

Comment: The answer is equal to the total number of ways you can re-arrange RAINBOW, minus the cases that don't fulfill the extra conditions.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I suggest thinking about the letters A,I,O being the dividers between the other letters.  Those three dividers create four "spaces" in which the other four letters (the consonants, as it happens) can be arbitrarily inserted.  Clearly there's a bit of work to do, but you should not post problems without trying them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: look at the problem as if you have 4 boxes _A_I_O_ where I put the dashes. Now can you figure out in how many ways you can place the remaining 4 letters in these boxes ( $C(4,4) $)? In the end you get $4!C(4,4)$ one for each permutation of the letters.

Each box can fit 0-4 letters and since we take all 4! permutations the order in which the letters are placed doesn’t matter.

Comment: What is $C(4,4)$? I think you need to expand on the number of ways to place the consonants (the right answer here is 840).

Comment: sir can you explain with proceduer that how you found 840 as answer

Comment: @Ritz: no, unfortunately, because you've shown no work of your own.

Comment: $C(4,4)$ is the number of ways 4 elements can be placed in 4 boxes not taking the order into consideration.